# Mutex or semaphore to prevent children threads to acess a file during log rotation by parent thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, binary-semaphore

My program has a main thread and a bunch of children threads that, among other stuff, write to the same log file. 
Once a day, the main thread checks if the log file is too big, then archives it, closes it and zips it.
A child thread, when it wants to write to the log, checks if the fd for the file is not null. If it's valid, it proceeds to write to the log and, if not, it starts a new log file. 
Problem is, due to concurrency, once in a blue moon the child thread will get the fd, everything looks good, but then it gets interrupted, the main thread archives the file and, by the time child thread resumes executing and tries to write to the log, fd is no longer valid and a segfault occurs.
So what is the best way to approach this? I thought about using the same mutex on main thread and the portion of child threads that do the log_write. That should solve this, but I don't really want to prevent more than one child thread to execute the log_write at the same time. Sure, the log might be a little messed, but for now this is not an issue for me. I just need a mechanism to prevent children threads to start writing to the log after the process of log archiving starts. 
Does this seem like a case for a semaphore?

Comment: My logger avoids all such issues entirely by queueing, (producer/consumer queue). all log requests to a dedicated logger thread.   This isolates logging latencies, archiving, daily log file changes, networked file delays etc etc from the originators of the log.

Comment: I think you are just attacking it from the wrong end. You should first open the file under a temporary name, exchange the file descriptors once that is done, and only after that do all the cleanup work, rename and compress the files etc.

Comment: What the other comments are alluding to without saying it is you have a fundamentally thread-unsafe design, and the only real fix is a redesign.  Or you can use your operating system's logging facilities and configure them to log to the file(s) you want - that's what they were designed to do.